Swagger useGenericResponse with specific endpoints
Right now, using swagger-codegen-cli v3.0.24 (unable to use latest at the moment) to generate jaxrs-cxf server API, I can set the property in my config.json useGenericResponse to true to support using the javax.ws.rs.core.Response class. This is great. Took me an embarrassingly long time to figure that out. Next problem I have is that not all endpoints in the API use that class as a response, but the property sets all responses in the API to that type during generation. Is there a way to get around this? If not, I'm guessing I'll have to generate generic responses separately from the specific ones.
Setting the response type in the different operations doesn't override the global setting ... at least not in the "traditional" way, as per below. I would think explicitly defining return types like this would override the generic property in each spot.
paths:
    /sample:
        get:
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: OK
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                type: array
                                items:
                                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/SampleDTO'


It seems that there is no inherent way to do this with configs or standard OpenAPI conventions. What I found is that creating a vendor extension that holds a boolean as to whether to use that class response or not in each operation then using it in template files is a way to override this. Specifically, using JavaJaxRS, customize the returnTypes.mustache template.
YAML Example:
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
servers:
paths:
    /sample:
        get:
            x-response: true

returnTypes.mustache changes:
{{#vendorExtensions.x-response}}Response{{/vendorExtensions.x-response}}{{! non-generic response:}}
{{^vendorExtensions.x-response}}{{!
}}{{{returnType}}}{{!
}}{{/vendorExtensions.x-response}}

One thing to consider is that doing this will override the useGenericResponse flag. If you want to continue having that option available, you'll have to account for that being set or not in the template.
